# NLB and persistent connections

Tags: windows

Good Day,

We are trying to implement network load balancing of windows in one of our high performing application, lets call it middleware. The middleware connects to three channels thorugh socket and the connection are persistent, means the clients remain connected between the transaction. We would like to distribute the work on nodes on the basis of transactions not the connections as there are only three. What approach should be taken.

Thanks
Mubashir

Comment: its windows 2003 Network load balancing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like Windows NLB only works with the on demand connection and obviously it has to, in order distribute load. we will be using MSMQ to distribute the transaction load itself accross all nodes.